# Сессии в CodeIgniter

Tags: сессия, php, codeigniter

Приветствую всех, недавно начал изучение PHP фреймворка и при работе с Library Session возникли некоторые проблемы, которые возможно могут вам показаться глупыми.

Собственно пишу страницу авторизации, в случае успешной авторизации пользователю присваивается идентификатор сессии, при этом сами сессии хранятся в БД. 
При каждом заходе на страницу авторизации по неведомым причинам старая сессия игнорируется и создается новая. Соответственно даже если пользователь авторизовался, то ему сначала присваивается нужная сессия, а при заходе/редиректе на другую страницу эта сессия заменяется на новую пустую

Из конфига:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cb_session';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'cb_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = ".localhost";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Сессии в базе:
[image]

Сессию собственноручно изменяют только в методе login:

```
public function login($data){
//...Проверка введенных данных...
        $this->session->set_userdata($authdata);
```

Comment: я не помню точно про сессии в CI (кроме того, что особых проблем не испытывал) но я вам настоятельно рекомендую прочитать следующий текст и сделать выводы http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/ellislab-seeking-new-owner-for-codeigniter (обратите внимание на дату сего поста)

Answer (score 1):

config.php выставь правильно

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://sваш домен';
```

и

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "ваш префикс_";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "ваш домен";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

и все заработает

Answer (score 0):

Я в своих проектах на CI не использую бд при работе с сессиями, они там недоделанные! 
поставьте `$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;` и работайте на здоровье.

Answer (score 0):

При создани таблицы для сессий необходимо указать размер user_agent >50 , например:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` 
(

 `session_id` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

 `ip_address` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

 `user_agent` varchar(120) NOT NULL,

 `last_activity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

 `user_data` text NOT NULL

) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Т.к. в вашем случае полное название user_agent не влазит, и создаётся новая сессия.